# Function returning object array of runtime determined enum types

Tags: c#, reflection

So I have a bunch of enum types (much more than this)

```
public enum Lobes
{
    Unspecified, 
    Frontal, 
    Parietal, 
    Temporal, 
    Occipital, 
    Hemispheric
}
public enum Predominantly
{
    Unspecified, 
    Frontal,
    Midline, 
    Occipital
}
public enum Asymmetric
{
    Unspecified,
    Unilateral,
    Bilateral
}
```

and I am storing the specified values as a dict:

```
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, int> Modifiers { get; private set; }
    public void SetModifiers(params object[] aEnums)
    {
        foreach (object aEnum in aEnums)
        {
            string myKey = aEnum.GetType().Name;
            int myValue = Convert.ToInt32(aEnum);

            if (Modifiers.ContainsKey(myKey))
            {
                Modifiers[myKey] = myValue;
            }
            else
            {
                Modifiers.Add(myKey, myValue);
            }
        }
    }
```

So far so good I guess. Now I want to create a function that returns an object array of the relevant enums. I'm guessing I have to use reflection, I've been reading a few answers on that but I'm a bit confused. So far I've tried:

```
    public object[] GetModifiers()
    {
        object[] returnObjects = new object[Modifiers.Count()];

        int i = 0;
        string nameSpaceOfAEnums = "Namespace.Is.Good";
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in Modifiers)
        {
            string enumName = nameSpaceOfAEnums + "." + pair.Key;
            // Doesn't work
            // returnObjects[i] = (Type.GetType(enumName))pair.Value;

            // would work if I go through all the different enums one by one: 
            returnObjects[i] = (Lobes) pair.Value;

            i++;
        }

        return returnObjects;
    }
```

Now, obviously, since I'm lazy, I don't really want a giant if-else if-else if soup checking for all the different enum types. Is it possible to achieve with reflection what I'm trying to do in this line:

```
            returnObjects[i] = (Type.GetType(enumName))pair.Value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Enum.ToObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.toobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var type = (Type.GetType(enumName);
returnObjects[i] = Enum.ToObject(type, pair.Value);
```

Comment: Ahh, I had tried that but I used Type instead of var (and possibly made some other error) - thank you! :)
Ed. Yea I had a cast in front of `Enum.ToObject`, which is not needed apparently.